# Cargar diferentes layouts

Tags: android, layout

Buenas! Dependiendo de un dato recibido me gustaría cargar en el setContentView un layout u otro. Yo he puesto lo siguiente:

```
//obtengo el dato enviado desde la otra activity
    dato = getIntent().getExtras().getInt("id");

Log.i("seguimiento", "antes del if " + getIntent().getExtras().getInt("id"));
    Log.i("seguimiento", "antes del if " + dato);
    if (dato == 7) {
        Log.i("seguimiento", "dentro del if " + dato);
        setContentView(R.layout.ficha_diferente);
    } else if (dato == 1 || dato == 2 || dato == 3 || dato == 4 || dato == 5 || dato == 6 || dato == 8){
        Log.i("seguimiento", "dentro del else if " + dato);
        setContentView(R.layout.ficha);
    } else if (dato == 9 || dato == 10 || dato == 11 || dato == 12 ){
        Log.i("seguimiento", "dentro del segundo else if " + dato);
        setContentView(R.layout.ficha_tarde);
    }
```

Entra correctamente en todos los if ya que lo rastreo con los Log, pero solo cuando dato == 1 || dato == 2 || dato == 3 || dato == 4 || dato == 5 || dato == 6 || dato == 8, es decir, cuando entra en el primer else if, es cuando me carga el layout en el resto me cierra la activity y me vuelve a la anterior.

Comment: deja comentado todo el código posteado y prueba cada setContentView(R.layout.1, 2 y 3); uno a la vez, para ver si es problema del layout.

Comment: Es correcto lo que realizas, el problema parece estar en los layout!, agrega el mensaje de LogCat y comenta.

Comment: Si gracias a todos, el problema estaba en los layout, ya lo he corregido y solucionado!!

Answer (score 1):

realmente no se porque no te funciona, deberia irte pero voy a comentarte como hago yo eso mismo. Lo que hago es llamar a un metodo que me devuelve un int que es la referencia al layout y eso es lo que cargo en el onCreate. Este seria el codigo para la funcion encargada de decirme cual seria el layout:

```
public int getLayout() {
        switch (tipo){
            case Producto.A:
            case Producto.B:
            case Producto.C:
            case Producto.D:
                return R.layout.generic;
            case  Producto.F:
                return R.layout.special;
        }
    return 0;
}
```

Y como te comentaba, en onCreate hago lo siguiente:

```
setContentView(getLayout());
```

Prueba a hacerlo con un switch en vez de un if y comentanos que tal.

Espero que te ayude.

Saludos.

Comment: Gracias, creo que tengo errores en los layouts y por eso no me los carga.